# R reads Google Drive CSV file as doctype HTML

Tags: html, r, csv, google-drive-api

I am learning how to read a .csv file from Google Drive.  Below is my file:

```
col1,col2
This is a test of R reading from a Google Drive.,This is only a test.
```

When I use R (3.3.2) to read the file in from C, it works as expected:

```
>test_file<-read.csv("C:/StackOverflow/GoogleTestRead.csv")
>print(test_file)

                                              col1                 col2
1 This is a test of R reading from a Google Drive. This is only a test.
```

When I try to read the same file over Google Drive, it can only appear as HTML, and has 2309 observations:

```
>file_id <- "0B30jSNRTe_XqX2xTWUplRFFHblk" 
>test_file <- read.csv(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", file_id), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>head(test_file,n=5) 
                                           X..DOCTYPE.html.
1                                            <html lang=en>
2                                                    <head>
3                                      <meta charset=utf-8>
4   <meta content=width=300, initial-scale=1 name=viewport>
5                        <meta name=robots content=noindex>
```

When I go to a browser and replace the *%s* in the sprintf reference with *file_id*, the browser correctly downloads the file, in the correct format.

Thank you for your suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: When I copy the URL to a browser i get "We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page" have you set it as only available to your account? In which case the browser will be keeping you logged on, but R won't have those logon details

Comment: Thank you Miff.  This is an intranet address within our company, so those outside the company would not have access.  However, I read in a csv file of a coworker successfully with this method.  Let me look at the options in my browser.

Comment: I have an answer.  I needed to install the R package "googlesheets" [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/googlesheets.pdf).  This allows R to cross the Google Drive authorization security.  After installing _googlesheets_, here is the code I needed.

Comment: `library(googlesheets)
#authorize google drive
gs_auth()
ss_in<-gs_key("1riTK38w63_Xjcpf2eIe3lsEd-vrC7-DjfRAwNWu15m0")
test_file<-as.data.frame(gs_read(ss_in))`


Note: the _gs_key_ can be found by viewing the document in Google Sheets, and copying the text between _/d_ and _/edit#.  Once the key is found, the csv file can be read in.  There are options in the _googlesheets_ library as well to find the _gs_key_ by the name or URL, but this direct form worked for me.